# Detection of low light images using SURF

Tags: c++, opencv, surf, light, object-detection

I have been using the code from [the OpenCV website](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) for detection of objects.I am a beginner to OpenCV and to image processing and have been trying to understand the working of SURF.I have a few doubts.

1.I have been using color images for detection and the results have been good so far.There are people who are recommending using grayscale images,will it increase the performance of the algorithm?

2.In the code,what is the significance of filtering by only having the matches with distance less than 3*mindist?

```
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
{ if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
     { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
}
```

3.Though the detection is robust in high illuminated images(i used 900 as the hessian value),the same image under low light conditions does not get detected with the same hessian value,is there a way to do both with the same hessian value and the same reference image for both conditions?Will cv::equalizeHist() be useful?If it is,can somebody please suggest a way for me to integrate with the SURF detection code?

4.DMatch structure which returns matches has a parameter called distance which returns the distance between descriptors.What does this mean?Is there a unit for the distance returned?

5.I would also like to know if there are better descriptors than SURF in terms of time complexity,scale and rotation invariance`for object detection.

Thanks in advance for your time and replies.

Answer (score 0):

1. SURF works with grayscale images.
2. There are lot of false random matches (since if you have 100 features in img1, you will always have 100 matches) and to filter them is good idea. But better is to check relative distance - how it is done in [Use Euclidean distance in SURF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812216/use-euclidean-distance-in-surf/19815769#19815769))
3. Yes, it can be used. You just use modified images instead of original.
   You detect low number of features because of low pixel intensity and low contrast in the dark regions, which decreases detector response. When applied to the dark image, histogram equalization increases contrast which increases number of local maximas below the threshold.

   cv::Mat img1, img1histEq;
   cv::equalizeHist(img1,img1histEq);
4. SURF is can be viewed as 128-dimentional vector. Distance is distance between two such vectors in some space, usually Euclidean - sum of squared differences between corresponding vector elements. Other metrics, e.g. L1 also can be used, but Euclidean is the most used for SURF.
5. SIFT performs better in terms of invariance, but 3 times slower. You can find comparison of the different descriptors [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/manik/projects/trade-off/papers/MikolajczykPAMI05.pdf) and [here](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/08/feature-descriptor-comparison-report/).
   It is not clear what do you mean by "object detection". What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: I gave the link from the OpenCV website.As for SIFT,i have heard about it,its very efficient.isnt there a faster alternative though?

Comment: (5) is answer to question about possible alternatives. It depends on your task. What do you mean by "I gave the link"?

Comment: Could you elaborate how equalizeHist() would help me under low light conditions for using SURF?

Comment: Sorry i meant am doing the detection as you asked me from the same code.A reference image detected on various scenes where it is present.

Comment: I have edited the answer. What you do is not "detection", it is matching the two views.