# Use Euclidean distance in SURF

Tags: c++, opencv, knn

In my code I'm filtering the good images based on the nearest neigbour distance ratio, as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) 
{
        if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && 
                                  ((int)matches[i].size()<=2 && (int)matches[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
 }
```

Since I'm filtering the good images based on the nearest neighbor distance ratio, do I need to still do Euclidean distance calculation?

And I want to know when I use the `knnMatch` method in `FlannBasedMatcher`, inside the method do they use the Euclidean distance to match the keypoints?

Comment: In my case if I'm not mistaken, distance is Hemming distance, not Euclidean (but I use BruteForceMatcher). Also I think knn doesn't give Euclidean distance because neighbor in array aren't neighbor in image. 
But I interesting too is there (in opencv) method giving Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need. Nearest neigbour distance ratio means that you: 
1)Calculate distances from the descriptor in one image to the the 1st and 2nd nearest neighbours in the second image. d1 = d(desc1_img1, descA_img2); d2 = d(desc1_img1, descB_img2).
2)Calculate distance ratio R = d1/d2.  If R < 0.6, then match is probably good. It is done because you will always got "nearest" descriptor in the second image, no matter how bad it is - you check it with ratio.

So if you have no distances, from what will you calculate ratio?

Type of distance depends on value you passed when constructed KNN-matcher in normType parameter.

```
 BFMatcher::BFMatcher(int normType=NORM_L2, bool crossCheck=false )
```

- NORM_L2 means Eucledian d(p1,p2) = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2+(y1 - y2)^2 +
  ...);
- NORM_Ll means Manhattan  d(p1,p2) = abs(x1 - x2)+abs(y1 - y2) +
  ..;
- NORM_HAMMING means [Hamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), etc.

Comment: No im using the knnMatch method and getting the matched keypoint values. Then filter the best matches using the above code based on the nearest neighbor distance.                                                         So if i need to check Euclidean distance, when should i check after the above code or when.

Comment: What you mean by "matched keypoint values"? KNN outputs you 2 things:
1)index of n-th nearest neighbour
2)distance to this n-th nearest neighbour.
Do you mean that you calculate some "Euclidian distance" additional to the knn-output?

Comment: Sry about that i was wrong in my previous comment. As you explained KNN output the distance to the nth nearest neighbour. is that distance is Euclidean distance or what?. can you please resolve this to me.

Comment: Have added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks alot for saving me old-ufo.

Comment: Ok, it Euclidean distance between neighbors in array, but not in neighbors in image. What logic? If neighbors are in image, there is logic but if neighbors in array are in different sides in image, what Euclidean distance gives me?

Comment: You are speaking about spatial distance between points - "how features are far from each other" and we are speaking about distance in some "similarity space" which means "how similar looking features are". That is completely different things.

Comment: I'm speaking about logic with looking similar with neighbors in array no image?

Comment: You have feature from image 1 and trying to find the most similar feature in image 2. Features from image 2 are in array. That is the standard approach in image matching.