# What is the meaning of min_dist and max_dist for SURF, FlannMatcher

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, surf

I'm using Opencv C++, for a face recognition application. For that I used `SURF` as descriptor and `FlannMatcher` for matching the points. My code is as follows,

```
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;  
std::vector< DMatch > matches;  
matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++ )
{ 
     double dist = matches[i].distance; 
     if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
     if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
}
```

Here we are finding `min_dist` and `max_dist` for checking whether there is a match between two faces.But I don't understand what this `min_dist` and `max_dist` means.

**What this exactly means? 
    Why we need to find both `min_dist` and `max_dist` for a single descriptor?**

Comment: It is known bad example. There is a better way how to distinguish good matches from bad, without this "max_dist" and "min_dist".
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19815769/1983544

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know SIFT descriptor is a vector in a high dimensional space, i.e 128. As you run it on the image to find interest points, it will find some points as interest points and their descriptor as a vector for each to describe this point in a high dimensional space.

Each of these points in the first image, say `A`, should have a corresponding in the other image, say `B`! It means that, **those who have a smallest distance are the most likely to be correspondent**, *But* **Not all of them**. Some of them may be *outliers* that we expect to have a high distance value in its detected correspondence.That makes us to use `max_dsist` in our code. In some types of contexts you may not want all the *best* matches because the number of correspondence points are maybe relatively high, or .... So we define a lower bound on the distance that we do that with `min_dist`.

I hope that gives you the insight!

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick response,it's really useful